# How do I modify solr query parameters conditionally in a custom SearchHandler?

Tags: solr

I have a query parameter which if matches some logic (say number range) I want to force set it in the request. Is this possible to do in a custom Handler? Basically a conditional update of a single request param.

Comment: Not that I'm familiar with. Maybe you can add logic in a reverse proxy in front of Solr, or maaaaybe by manually hacking the Jetty configuration (generally not recommended as it makes upgrading harder and could cause weird errors down the line). Otherwise your app / client library is probably the place to do something like that.

Comment: @MatsLindh I am not sure I was clear. I qualified further. I am new to solr, pardon my verbiage if unclear. I am looking to force set the rows to a smaller value.if user gave a huge number. I am trying to do it via ModifiableParams, no luck yet

Comment: You can't do it conditionally, but you can lock it to a specific value using `invariant` in your handler configuration.

Comment: @MatsLindh Invariant is a blanket forcing right? What if I want to force rows=50 ONLY when user queried with &rows=500 (basically if the input param is more than the desired limit)

Comment: Correct. And no, you can't do it conditionally as far as I know.